# Optimizing query for calculating Median using GROUP BY & ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Please see below for a sample portion of my MySQL table:

Table name: **eb_tickets**

```
+-------------------+----------------------+
|  ticket_type      |  time_first_response |
|  Standard Traffic |  0:18:14             |
|  Standard Traffic |  0:48:06             |
|  Miscellaneous    |  44:12:23            |
|  Feed             |  4:48:22             | 
|  Miscellaneous    |  15:33:20            |
|  Banners          |  21:00:02            |
|  Integration      |  36:00:02            |
+-------------------+----------------------+
```

I want to output the response like so, calculating the median value with distinct values ASC:

```
+-------------------+----------------------+
|  median_group     |  median              | 
|  Banners          |  21:00:02            |
|  Feed             |  4:48:22             | 
|  Integration      |  36:00:02            |
|  Miscellaneous    |  32:36:13            |
|  Standard Traffic |  0:33:10             |
+-------------------+----------------------+
```

Currently, I am achieving this with the following query:

```
SET @row_number:=0; 
SET @median_group:='';

SELECT 
    median_group, AVG(time_first_response) AS median
FROM
(SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @median_group = ticket_type THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS count_of_group,
    @median_group:=ticket_type AS median_group,
    ticket_type,
    time_first_response,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            eb_tickets
        WHERE
            a.ticket_type = ticket_type) AS total_of_group 
FROM
    (SELECT 
        ticket_type, time_first_response
    FROM
        eb_tickets           
    ORDER BY ticket_type, time_first_response) AS a) AS b
    WHERE
    count_of_group BETWEEN total_of_group / 2.0 AND total_of_group / 2.0 +1
    GROUP BY median_group
```

Unfortunately, this query is taking around 1 second per record, and I am querying thousands of records with the possibility of 20 different values for the ticket_type column.

Is it possible to optimize my current query in an attempt to make the query perform faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try like this?

```
SELECT counter.ticket_type,AVG(time_first_response) AS median FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      IF(@type = type, @ctr := @ctr + 1, @ctr := 1) AS rownum, 
      @type := ticket_type AS ticket_type,
      time_first_response
    FROM eb_tickets
    ORDER BY ticket_type,time_first_response
  ) AS counter,
  (
    SELECT ticket_type, COUNT(*) AS rows
    FROM eb_tickets
    GROUP BY ticket_type
  ) AS types
  WHERE types.ticket_type = counter.ticket_type AND
    CASE rows % 2 
      WHEN 1 THEN rownum IN (ROUND(rows / 2),ROUND(rows / 2))
      ELSE rownum IN (ROUND(rows / 2),ROUND(rows / 2) + 1)
    END
  GROUP BY counter.ticket_type
```

Initially, while I was experimenting on the SQL I used shorter names for the columns - `type` instead of `ticket_type` and the subquery `counter` was left with the wrong column name `type` instead of `ticket_type`

Comment: I used counter.type instead instead of counter.ticket_type because I was getting an error about counter.ticket_type not existing, and it is only returning partial results (although the results are correct). So it is returning the ticket types and the correct medians, however it is not including all of the ticket types in the results. Was changing counter.ticket_type to counter.type the right move?

Comment: I also edited `GROUP BY ticket_type` to be `GROUP BY ticket_type,time_first_response` and now I am getting the full result set with close accuracy to my original query. Now I am not sure which query is accurate :/ However this saved a massive amount of time in the query.
118 seconds for 10 records VS 1 second for 10 records.

Comment: Doing some testing to see which one is more accurate :)

Comment: Yours is more accurate and faster (with the above adjustments).
Thank you sir!